# Recount lastRow in ActiveSheet after Deleting Blank Cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I recount the lastRow of an `Activesheet` after deleting the blank cells from the `Activesheet` so I will get a new lastRow variable to be my maximum limit? My data came from a web query.

Example:

1. data source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_bear
2. number of rows after import: 1360
3. number of rows after deleting blank cells: 650

But the `ActiveSheet` is not refreshed and lastRow is not updated to 650, i would like those to be updated

Comment: using `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` in your code will recalculate the used range

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a common requirement when writing VBA for Excel, you may want to write a function that you can reuse in other projects. Here is an example:

```
Function get_end_row(ByVal column_with_data As Long) As Long
Dim last_row As Long

last_row = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count


get_end_row = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(last_row, column_with_data).End(xlUp).Row
''Note: in the line of code above you can replace xlUp with its hexidecimal value -> &HFFFFEFBE
''This will ensure the function works in other versions of Excel    

End Function
```

Here is an example of how the function is called:

```
Sub my_routine()
Dim endRow As Long

''The 1 being passed in the argument below is the first column number that your data is in
endRow = get_end_row(1)

Msgbox endRow

End Sub
```

In your case, make sure you call the get_end_row() function after you have deleted the rows.