# Lastrow Variable - Only reading to the lastrow of the first data set after merging with another data set

Tags: excel, vba

First, I am merging two datasets onto a new tab named "combine" (which has 4900 rows)
Second, I am removing duplicates from the "combine" tab (after removing duplicates it has 4000 rows)
Lastly, I am trying to merge another dataset onto the last row of the "combine" tab.

The issue: My VBA code is pasting the last dataset onto the 4900th row instead of the 4000. Any idea how I can fix this so that the dataset in the last step is copying to the new lastrow of the combine tab ?

Comment: refind the last row before merging?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171316/recount-lastrow-in-activesheet-after-deleting-blank-cells-in-vba

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442159/vba-dynamically-change-lastrow

Comment: Sounds like you need to the your last row *after* the duplicates have been removed? Hard to tell without seeing any of your code. Please see [mcve]

Comment: You need to find the row of code where the last row is calculated then copy that line and paste it into your code block to a line after all the above things you mentioned have already been executed... As simple as that...